Type error on AWS SSM Document For each loop
I am currently trying to create my custom SSM document that aims to create/delete VPC Endpoints when needed. The problem is that I don't understand of to iterate over a MapList with SSM Document.
The sample input that I used is :
[
{
"VpcId": "vpc-*",
"SubnetIds": ["subnet-*"],
"ServiceName": "com.amazonaws.eu-west-3.s3",
"Name": "TestEndpoint"
},
{
"VpcId": "vpc-*",
"SubnetIds": ["subnet-*"],
"ServiceName": "com.amazonaws.eu-west-3.dynamodb",
"Name": "TestEndpoint2"
}
]

With the Document content :
schemaVersion: '0.3'
description: |-
  *Replace this default text with instructions or other information about your runbook.*

parameters:
  VpcEndpoints:
    type: MapList
mainSteps:
  - name: Loop
    action: aws:loop
    isEnd: true
    inputs:
      Iterators: '{{ VpcEndpoints }}'
      IteratorDataType: StringMap
      Steps:
        - name: CreateVpcEndpoint
          action: aws:executeAwsApi
          isEnd: true
          inputs:
            Service: ec2
            Api: CreateVpcEndpoint
            VpcEndpointType: Interface
            VpcId: '{{ Loop.CurrentIteratorValue }}.VcpId'
            SubnetIds: '{{ Loop.CurrentIteratorValue }}.SubnetIds'
            ServiceName: '{{ Loop.CurrentIteratorValue }}.ServiceName'
            TagSpecifications:
              - ResourceType: vpc-endpoint
                Tags:
                  - Key: Name
                    Value: '{{ Loop.CurrentIteratorValue }}.Name'

And I finally received this error :
Step fails when it is validating and resolving the step inputs. Failed to resolve input: VpcEndpoints to type StringList. VpcEndpoints is found to be of type MapList.. Please refer to Automation Service Troubleshooting Guide for more diagnosis details.
I am not sure where is my misunderstanding in the parameters type and searching for someone that already tried to iterate over a MapList within an SSM Document.
